# Obliterate the "high" tag

Tags: support, tags, moderators

The [high] tag serves no useful purpose and should be deleted.

https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/high

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Someone with enough rep created it, and then it got added on by a bunch of new users. I've edited it away. I've also done the same on the [low](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/low) tag.